# What's the difference between a proxy server and a reverse proxy server?

Tags: proxy, webserver, terminology, reverse-proxy

What is the difference between a proxy server and a reverse proxy server?

Comment: It's well explained in [Apache docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html#forwardreverse), too.

Comment: @Paolo that made it _much_ easier to understand than the Wikipedia article. Perhaps I should get around to editing some of that info into the Wikipedia article eventually...

Comment: Lets say I have host A which needs to connect to host C, but doesn't directly. Instead, it is configured as a with host entry or possibly dns, to call B which forwards the request to C. C doesn't care or know about B.

Is this a forward proxy or a reverse proxy?

Comment: If host A can't get to host C without being configured to first contact host B, then host B is a traditional forward or "outbound" proxy server.

Comment: Forward proxies grant the client anonymity (i.e, think Tor). Reverse proxies grant back end servers anonymity (i.e, think servers behind a DMZ).

Answer (score 3177):

The previous answers were accurate, but perhaps too terse.
I will try to add some examples.

First of all, the word "proxy" describes someone or something acting on behalf of someone else.

In the computer realm, we are talking about one server acting on the behalf of another computer.

For the purposes of accessibility, I will limit my discussion to web proxies - however, the idea of a proxy is not limited to websites.

## FORWARD proxy

Most discussion of web proxies refers to the type of proxy known as a "forward proxy."

The proxy event, in this case, is that the "forward proxy" retrieves data from another web site on behalf of the original requestee.

### A tale of 3 computers (part I)

For an example, I will list three computers connected to the internet.

- X = your computer, or "client" computer on the internet
- Y = the proxy web site, proxy.example.org
- Z = the web site you want to visit, www.example.net

Normally, one would connect directly from `X --> Z.`

However, in some scenarios, it is better for `Y --> Z` on behalf of `X`,
which chains as follows: `X --> Y --> Z`.

### Reasons why X would want to use a forward proxy server:

Here is a (very) partial list of uses of a forward proxy server:

- 1) X is unable to access Z directly
  because

  - a) Someone with administrative authority over `X`'s internet connection has decided to block all access to site `Z`.

    - Examples:

      - The Storm Worm virus is spreading by tricking people into visiting `familypostcards2008.com`, so the system administrator has blocked access to the site to prevent users from inadvertently infecting themselves.
      - Employees at a large company have been wasting too much time on `facebook.com`, so management wants access blocked during business hours.
      - A local elementary school disallows internet access to the `playboy.com` website.
      - A government is unable to control the publishing of news, so it controls access to news instead, by blocking sites such as `wikipedia.org`. See [TOR](https://www.onion-router.net/) or [FreeNet](https://freenetproject.org/).
  - b) The administrator of `Z` has blocked `X`.

    - Examples:

      - The administrator of Z has noticed hacking attempts coming from X, so the administrator has decided to block X's IP address (and/or netrange).
      - Z is a forum website.  `X` is spamming the forum. Z blocks X.

## REVERSE proxy

### A tale of 3 computers (part II)

For this example, I will list three computers connected to the internet.

- X = your computer, or "client" computer on the internet
- Y = the reverse proxy web site, proxy.example.com
- Z = the web site you want to visit, www.example.net

Normally, one would connect directly from `X --> Z.`

However, in some scenarios, it is better for the administrator of `Z` to restrict or disallow direct access and force visitors to go through Y first.
So, as before, we have data being retrieved by `Y --> Z` on behalf of `X`, which chains as follows: `X --> Y --> Z`.

What is different this time compared to a "forward proxy," is that this time the user `X` does not know he is accessing `Z`, because the user `X` only sees he is communicating with `Y`.
The server `Z` is invisible to clients and only the reverse proxy `Y` is visible externally. A reverse proxy requires no (proxy) configuration on the client side.

The client `X` thinks he is only communicating with `Y` (`X --> Y`), but the reality is that `Y` forwarding all communication (`X --> Y --> Z` again).

### Reasons why Z would want to set up a reverse proxy server:

- 1) Z wants to force all traffic to its web site to pass through Y first.

  - a) Z has a large web site that millions of people want to see, but a single web server cannot handle all the traffic. So Z sets up many servers and puts a reverse proxy on the internet that will send users to the server closest to them when they try to visit Z. This is part of how the Content Distribution Network (CDN) concept works.

    - Examples:

      - [Apple Trailers](https://www.apple.com/trailers/) uses [Akamai](https://www.akamai.com/)
      - Jquery.com hosts its JavaScript files using [CloudFront CDN](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/) ([sample](https://static.jquery.com/files/rocker/scripts/custom.js)).
      - etc.
- 2) The administrator of Z is worried about retaliation for content hosted on the server and does not want to expose the main server directly to the public.

  - a) Owners of Spam brands such as "Canadian Pharmacy" appear to have thousands of servers, while in reality having most websites hosted on far fewer servers. Additionally, abuse complaints about the spam will only shut down the public servers, not the main server.

In the above scenarios, `Z` has the ability to choose `Y`.

## Links to topics from the post:

### Content Delivery Network

- Lists of CDNs

  - http://www.mytestbox.com/miscellaneous/content-delivery-networks-cdn-list/
  - http://blog.streamingmedia.com/the_business_of_online_vi/2008/01/updated-list-of.html

### Forward proxy software (server side)

- [PHP-Proxy](https://www.php-proxy.com/)
- [cgi-proxy](https://www.jmarshall.com/tools/cgiproxy/)
- [phproxy](https://sourceforge.net/projects/poxy/)  (discontinued)
- [glype](http://www.glype.com/)
- [Internet censorship wiki: List of Web Proxies](http://en.cship.org/wiki/Category:Webproxy)
- [squid](http://www.squid-cache.org/)  (apparently, can also work as a reverse proxy)

### Reverse proxy software for HTTP (server side)

- [Apache mod_proxy](http://wiki.apache.org/cocoon/ApacheModProxy) (can also work as a forward proxy for HTTP)
- [nginx](https://nginx.org/)  (used on hulu.com, spam sites, etc.)
- [HAProxy](https://www.haproxy.org/)
- [Caddy Webserver](https://caddyserver.com/docs/proxy)
- [lighthttpd](https://redmine.lighttpd.net/projects/lighttpd)
- [perlbal](https://github.com/perlbal/) (written for livejournal)
- [portfusion](https://github.com/corsis/PortFusion#readme)
- [pound](http://www.apsis.ch/pound/)
- [varnish cache](https://varnish-cache.org/) (written by a [FreeBSD kernel guru](https://info.varnish-software.com/blog/celebrating-10-years-of-varnish-cache-qa-with-the-man-behind-the-idea))
- [repose](https://repose.atlassian.net/wiki/)

### Reverse proxy software for TCP (server side)

- [balance](https://www.inlab.net/balance/)
- [delegate](http://www.delegate.org/delegate/nvproxy/)
- [pen](http://siag.nu/pen/)
- [portfusion](https://github.com/corsis/PortFusion#readme)
- [pure load balancer](https://web.archive.org/web/20080113185334/http://plb.sunsite.dk/index.html) (web site defunct)
- [python director](http://pythondirector.sourceforge.net/)

### See also:

- [Wikipedia - Content Delivery Network](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_Delivery_Network)
- [Wikipedia - Category:Reverse_proxy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Reverse_proxy)
- [Wikipedia - Load Balancing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Load_balancing_(computing))
- [Wikipedia - Scalability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalability)

Comment: TAM (tivoli access manager) is also a reverse proxy server, right?

Comment: what about open-proxy??

Comment: Conceptually then, we could refer to or think of a "reverse proxy" then as a "forced" proxy?

Comment: Anything about the position of the firewall and its justification?

Comment: HAProxy can act as both HTTP and TCP reverse proxy.  A reverse proxy can also add basic http authentication to your system (you may have a web server or device with integrated web service, then you can use HAProxy to add authentication, if device does not have any.).  You do also use reverse proxy to make more robust system.

Comment: "that will send users to the server closest to them" - What is the point? All the traffic will go through that proxy server, right? So it does not matter where location of 'local' server behind it is. Or I am missing something?

Comment: Are reverse proxy server and the main server are on the same server or can they be different?

Comment: @Pavel probably "server closest to them" isn't the best description. More like "distribute load to pool of servers" is better description. This example was describing a reverse proxy load balancer.

Comment: @qyb2zm302 `What is different this time compared to a "forward proxy," is that this time the user X does not know he is accessing Z` But since `Z` is example.com, wouldn't the user not know he is actually accessing `X`? This seems like it implies that the user has visited `Y = the reverse proxy web site, proxy.example.com`?

Comment: You can almost think of a reverse proxy as load balancing.

Comment: Wouldn't the forward proxy software be client side?  You mentioned:

`forward proxy software (server side)`

Comment: Squid should also appear in reverse proxy... It's a good product as reverse proxy too. Was first used by yahoo and I believe still is.

Comment: Your point says `but the reality is that Y forwarding all communication to  Z again` so what is the  use of reverse proxy if the requests hits `Z` again ? What does the multiple servers in Y does ?

Comment: Probably repeated somewhere in comments but you state the difference of reverse is that the user X is unaware of Z. Isn't the same true in the forward proxy?

The other answers saying acting on behalf of client or server combined with your examples is a good explanation imo. (I think more times than not, you assume X is unaware) "Y" would either act on behalf of X or behalf of Z. So maybe it's more Y is aware of X or Y is aware of Z.

Comment: so when specific web sites are restricted by ISP , reverse proxy will allow user to access them , right?

Comment: that local elementary school is so cruel!

Comment: This was the key for me:- forward: `(X --> Y) --> Z`, reverse: `X --> (Y --> Z)`.

Comment: That was the best post I've ever seen on stack overflow.  Well done.  (stands and claps).  Really appreciate the effort that went into that.

Comment: I'm adding this explanation to our Developer / DevOps Playbook. Excellent explanation, thank you. What exactly is a SOCKS 5 proxy for? Example: https://shadowsocks.org/en/index.html

Comment: If they use both forward and reverse this is how I think of it `x <--> (Px <--> Pz) <--> z`

Comment: Can someone clarify this point "X is unable to access Z directly because" further? Does this mean access to Z is blocked by adding proxy or access to Z is enabled by using forward proxy?

Comment: What's the use of a "server side forward proxy"?

Comment: @MinhNghĩa @Sid A web proxy (either forward or reverse) is a `server acting on the behalf of another computer`. So I think the term **Forward proxy software (server side)** refers to the software that allows you to run a server as a forward proxy server.

Comment: @Miguel it's "access to Z is enabled by using forward proxy". For example on the case when a company restricts access to facebook.com, it's usually done by adding a blacklist of blocked sites (so all sites listed on the list cannot be accessed by the employes). If an employee tries to access facebook.com using a proxy server (assuming the proxy is not blacklisted), the company system will see the access as non-restricted, as the request destination is the proxy server (not facebook.com)

Comment: Too much needless information. This begs the question: why does this trivial topic invite confusion? The answer is the "reverse" adjective and you would do well to just ignore it.  There are local proxies (outbound control) and remote proxies (inbound control) and the applications of both do not require a lot of imagination.  The picture in #417 is excellent but keep in mind you can replace the people icons with devices or servers that generate outbound requests.

Comment: This is an incredible answer and I applaud @qyb2zm302 for writing it.

Comment: I got a question. As a forward proxy, it controls the egress traffic. But if one inside the proxy's domain try to access a blocked site by sending request to its own reverse proxy which located outside of the forward proxy, doesn't it means that the forward proxy is being compromised (bypassed)?

Comment: Well that makes the concept clear. But still the question is why the name 'reverse'? I couldn't see any reverse effect in case of reverse proxy.
One possible reason I can guess is, in case of 'forward proxy' the requirement of a proxy is from the side of X, while in case of 'reverse proxy' the requirement of a proxy is from the side of server Z. Does that make sense?

Comment: Proxy: X asks Y to act on his behalf, 
Reverse Proxy: Z asks Y to act on his behalf

Answer (score 587):

A pair of simple definitions would be:

Forward Proxy: Acting on behalf of a requestor (or service consumer)

Reverse Proxy: Acting on behalf of  service/content producer.

Answer (score 485):

I found the diagram below to be very helpful. It just shows the architecture of a *forward* vs. *reverse* proxy setup from client to server over the Internet. This image will help you to understand [qyb2zm302's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/366212/452102) and other answers better.

[image: Forward Proxy vs Reverse Proxy]

You can also watch [this video](https://youtu.be/jGQTS1CxZTE) from *F5*'s *DevCentral* by Peter Silva.

Picture Source: [Quora](http://qr.ae/TU1LIV). However, as per [Martijn Pieters](https://stackoverflow.com/users/100297/martijn-pieters), this image could be from [Pulse Secure Community](https://community.pulsesecure.net/t5/Pulse-Secure-vADC/Using-Stingray-Traffic-Manager-as-a-Forward-Proxy/ta-p/28747) or Julien Pauli's [site](https://julien-pauli.developpez.com/tutoriels/web/http/?page=page_7) (in French) at developpez.com.

It reminded me of the classic proverb:

> A picture is worth 1000 words.

Comment: This is really all you need to look at. Setting up a proxy in your browser so that Netflix doesn't know what country you're in is a forward proxy; an upstream service that directs an incoming request (perhaps you want to send one request to two servers) is a reverse proxy.

Comment: Forward proxy can be on internet as well

Comment: The best picture in the last answer. Thanks. :) A reverse proxy is also known as "Load Balancer" and acts on the server-side (distribute load to different servers), while a forward proxy supports the client side.

Comment: I am trying to understand the second picture. As said `Reverse proxy server` has multiple servers in it , but main server which is hidden from public should sit back of multiple servers , but i can't see the main sever in picture ?

Comment: Notice that "A load balancer can balance traffic from layer 3 upwards to layer 7, but a reverse proxy is HTTP specific." For more: https://serverfault.com/questions/127021/what-is-the-difference-between-load-balancer-and-reverse-proxy

Comment: The quora author is not the original author of the image, as [this page from 2013 with a single revision](https://community.pulsesecure.net/t5/Pulse-Secure-vADC/Using-Stingray-Traffic-Manager-as-a-Forward-Proxy/ta-p/28747) is a year older.

Comment: It may be that [this french tutorial from 2009](https://julien-pauli.developpez.com/tutoriels/web/http/?page=page_7) is the source; the [2009 web archive copy](https://web.archive.org/web/20090801000000*/http://julien-pauli.developpez.com:80/tutoriels/web/http/?page=page_7) is having javascript issues (continued redirects), and the images were only archived in 2017, but the source references the same image URLs as later sources.

Comment: Thanks for the info @MartijnPieters. I will update my answer accordingly.

Comment: @mac Could you elaborate? The top answer also mentioned "server side forward proxy", what's the use of these things?

Comment: Yes, the image is actually from Pulse Secure technical documentation page. Thanks @MartijnPieters

Comment: A picture worth hundred/thousands words!!

Answer (score 260):

*[Forward Proxy vs. Reverse Proxy](http://www.jscape.com/blog/bid/87783/Forward-Proxy-vs-Reverse-Proxy)* (2012) explains the difference between forward and reverse proxies very clearly.

[qyb2zm302's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/224664/whats-the-difference-between-a-proxy-server-and-a-reverse-proxy-server/366212#366212) nicely details applications of proxies, but it slips up on the fundamental concept between forward and reverse proxies. For the reverse proxy, X → Y → Z, X knows about Y and not Z, rather than vice versa.

A proxy is simply a middleman for communication (requests + responses). Client <-> Proxy <-> Server

- Client proxy: **(** client <-> proxy **)** <-> server

The proxy acts on behalf of the client. The client knows about all three machines involved in the chain. The server doesn't.

- Server proxy: client <-> **(** proxy <-> server **)**

The proxy acts on behalf of the server. The client only knows about the proxy. The server knows the whole chain.

It seems to me that *forward* and *reverse* are simply confusing, perspective-dependent names for *client* and *server* proxy. I suggest abandoning the former for the latter, for explicit communication.

Of course, to further complicate the matter, not every machine is exclusively a client or a server. If there is an ambiguity in context, it's best to explicitly specify where the proxy lies, and the communications that it tunnels.

Comment: This answer is in line with http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_proxy.html#forwardreverse and helps explain it clearly

Comment: it seems that the most relevant feature in this comparison is who-knows-who. forward proxy: client knows both proxy (it has it configured in fact) and target server (as it makes request to url of server), while, in the case of reverse proxy, the client knows of the proxy as a target server (it does not know what the proxy is actually calling; it can be one server or more). with a forward proxy, the server does not know who the clients really are, as the proxy "forwards" request to it. forward proxy: hide client(s). reverse proxy: hide server(s).

Comment: @Protongun "..A proxy is simply a middleman for communication (requests + responses).." what's the need of proxy in first place ? Please clarify. IMHO this answer should have been the accepted one

Comment: The first link in this post makes it clear and easy to understand for everybody

Comment: @Belun Well explained in utmost simple words/terms.

Comment: Why are there server-side client/forward proxy software? Is it just "reverse proxy, without sending the client information"? And what is a piece of software which "hide" both client and server called?

Answer (score 131):

Some diagrams might help:

**Forward proxy**

[image: Forward proxy]

**Reverse proxy**

[image: Reverse proxy]

Comment: Is it? They look the same! What is so special about re-writing a response that makes a proxy a "reverse" proxy?

Comment: @8bitjunkie Its about perspective. Notice that, for the forward proxy, the client knows it is communicating with a proxy server. For the reverse proxy, the client thinks it is communicating directly with home.com.

The proxies also have different implementations. The reverse proxy can be pretty stupid. All it has to do is change the address and pass the call along. More networking logic on client, less on the proxy.

The forward proxy, on the other hand, needs to somehow know that a request for proxy.com() requires a call to service.com. Less networking logic on client, more on the proxy.

Comment: What is meant by "**translate** myhome.myhosting.com to hom.com" I don't get the translate part. Like re-write part of the response header or something?

Comment: Also one of the reasons for reverse proxy (based on what I understood from the accepted answer) is that the purpose of doing this is to divide heavy incoming traffic amongst multiple servers. Where in this chain does that happen? Is that another "inbound rule"?

Comment: @1252748 about 1), the translation would simply mean mapping the URLs and issuing a request to the appropriate URL. about 2), yes, you can configure the server to, for instance, use round robin to load balance the requests among servers.

Comment: Is it your own diagram? Or is there a source?

Comment: @PeterMortensen they are my own

Answer (score 75):

The difference is primarily in deployment. Web forward and reverse proxies all have the same underlying features. They accept requests for HTTP requests in various formats and provide a response, usually by accessing the origin or contact server.

Fully featured servers usually have access control, caching, and some link-mapping features.

A forward proxy is a proxy that is accessed by configuring the client machine. The client needs protocol support for proxy features (redirection, proxy authentication, etc.). The proxy is transparent to the user experience, but not to the application.

A reverse proxy is a proxy that is deployed as a web server and behaves like a web server, with the exception that instead of locally composing the content from programs and disk, it forwards the request to an origin server. From the client perspective it *is* a web server, so the user experience is completely transparent.

In fact, a single proxy instance can run as a forward and reverse proxy at the same time for different client populations.

Comment: Just to be sure, a forward proxy is client-side and a reverse proxy is server-side?

Comment: @yves. a proxy is also a server. It is just that client need a local configuration so that they can communicate. While a reverse proxy requires configuration at the server itself. Their physical nodes  are both at the 'server side'.

Comment: Just for general info, not _all_ proxies can operate as forward and reverse, e.g., SOCKS can, but not HTTP proxies.

Answer (score 71):

**Proxy: It is making the request on behalf of the client**. So, the server will return the response to the proxy, and the proxy will forward the response to the client. In fact, the server will never "learn" who the client was (the client's IP address); it will only know the proxy. However, the client definitely knows the server, since it essentially formats the HTTP request destined for the server, but it just hands it to the proxy.

[image]

**Reverse Proxy: It is receiving the request on behalf of the server**. It forwards the request to the server, receives the response and then returns the response to the client. In this case, the client will never "learn" who was the actual server (the server's IP address) (with some exceptions); it will only know the proxy. The server will or won't know the actual client, depending on the configurations of the reverse proxy.

[image]

Comment: I feel like I could copy and paste your definitions backwards and that they would still be true. I don't think this explains any key difference or clarifies what is so "reverse" about a reverse proxy?

Comment: The proxy will always act on behalf of someone (hiding its identity from the other party). The "reverse" refers to reversing the side of which is "hidden", with it being client on the first case (regular proxy) and server on the second case (reverse proxy). Indeed, the terms could be used interchangeably, it's just a matter of convention having selected the first case as the regular proxy (probably for historic reasons). Hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 53):

The best explanation is [here](http://www.jscape.com/blog/bid/87783/Forward-Proxy-vs-Reverse-Proxy) with diagrams:

While a ***forward proxy*** proxies on behalf of clients **(** or requesting hosts **)**, a ***reverse proxy*** proxies on behalf of servers.

In effect, whereas a ***forward proxy*** hides the identities of clients, a ***reverse proxy*** hides the identities of servers.

Answer (score 40):

A proxy server proxies (and optionally caches) outgoing network requests to various not-necessarily-related public resources across the Internet. A reverse proxy captures (and optionally caches) incoming requests from the Internet and distributes them to various internal private resources, usually for high availability purposes.

Answer (score 33):

**Proxy (Forward Proxy):**

When computers on your LAN connect to a proxy server that accesses the Internet. Benefits include only the server being exposed to the Internet. People on the outside are unable to access the computers directly.
Forward proxies can improve Internet access for users by caching downloads. They can also be used to restrict access to certain sites. Also, only the proxy server would need a public address, not the clients connecting to it.

**Reverse Proxy:**

A reverse proxy is the opposite of a forward proxy. Instead it acts as a proxy on behalf of the servers being connected to. Instead of accessing a remote server directly, a user would go through the reverse proxy and get directed to the appropriate 
server from there. Only the reverse proxy would need an SSL certificate, only one public IP address would be needed, and it can handle load balancing of incoming requests to enhance the overall user experience.

[image]

*Image Source: [Creating a Forward Proxy Using Application Request Routing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/configuring-application-request-routing-arr/creating-a-forward-proxy-using-application-request-routing)*

Comment: IMHO, simplest/best answer.

Answer (score 33):

> [Cloudflare](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cloudflare) has a great article with images explaining this in details.
>
> Check here:
>   *[What Is A Reverse Proxy? | Proxy Servers Explained](https://www.cloudflare.com/learning/cdn/glossary/reverse-proxy/)*

[image]

---

[image]

Answer (score 13):

My understanding from an [Apache](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_HTTP_Server) perspective is that proxy means that if site x proxies for site y, then requests for x return y.

The reverse proxy means that the response from y is adjusted so that all references to y become x.

So that the user cannot tell that a proxy is involved...

Answer (score 13):

**Forward proxies** grant the client anonymity (i.e, think [Tor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tor_%28anonymity_network%29)).

**Reverse proxies** grant back end servers anonymity (i.e, think servers behind a DMZ).

Comment: https://aarvy.me/blog/2019/09/30/what-is-reverse-proxy-live-example-2019/

Answer (score 12):

As per my understanding...

To start with, as everyone knows, proxy means "the authority to represent someone else". Now there are two things, forward and reverse proxy.

#### Forward proxy

Suppose you want to access "Google" and "Google" in turn will have n number of servers to respond to that particular request.

Now in this case, while you are requesting for something from Google and you don’t want Google to see your IP address, then you will use a forward proxy, as explained below.

A → B → C

Now here you are A, sending a request through B. So C will think that the request is coming from B, not A. In this way you can prevent your clients IP address not to be exposed to outer world.

#### Reverse proxy

Now in this case, to make you understand, we will take the same case of forward proxy. Here you have requested for something to Google, which in turn going to send the one request to the app server or another proxy server to get the response. So these things will happen as explained below.

A  → B  → C

C  → D

C  ← D

A ← B ← C

From the above diagram you can see that a request has been sent to C from B, not from A. Then from C there will be one request send to D. Similarly the response will go to C from D and then to B and A.

The above diagram says it's only the context which matters although both the proxies are acting the same way, but the client-side proxy is hiding the client information whereas the server-side proxy will hide server-side information.

Answer (score 9):

Here's an example of a reverse proxy (as a load balancer).

A client surfs to website.com and the server it hits has a reverse proxy running on it. The reverse proxy happens to be [Pound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pound_%28networking%29). Pound takes the request and sends it to one of the three application servers sitting behind it. In this example, Pound is a load balancer. That is, it is balancing the load between three application servers.

The application servers serve up the website content back to the client.

Answer (score 8):

**A forward proxy** serves **users**: it helps **users** access the **server**.

**A reverse proxy** serves **the server**: it protects **the server** from **users**.

Answer (score 6):

Difference between **Proxy server** (also called forward proxy) and **Reverse Proxy Server** depends on the point of reference.

Technically, both are exactly the same. Both serve the same purpose of transmitting data  to a destination on behalf of a source.

The difference lies in **'on whose behalf is the proxy server acting / who is the proxy server representing?'**

If the proxy server is forwarding requests to internet server on behalf of the end users (Example: students in a college accessing internet through college proxy server.), then the proxy is called 'Forward proxy' or simply 'Proxy'.

If the proxy server is responding to incoming requests, on behalf of a server, then the proxy is called **'Reverse Proxy'**, as it is working in the reverse direction, from the point of view of the end user.

**Some Examples of Reverse proxies:**

1. Load balancer in front of web servers acts as a reverse-proxy on behalf of the actual web servers.
2. API gateway
3. Free Website hosting services like (facebook pages / blog page servers) are also reverse proxies. The actual content may be in some web server, but the outside world knows it through specific url advertised by reverse-proxy.

**Use of forward proxy:**

1. Monitor all outbound internet connections from an organization
2. Apply security policies on internet browsing and block malicious content from being downloaded
3. Block access to specific websites

**Use of Reverse proxy:**

1. Present friendly URL for a website
2. Perform load balancing across multiple web servers
3. Apply security policy and protect actual web servers from attacks

Answer (score 5):

**If no proxy**

To see from the client side and server side are the same:

Client   ->   Server

**Proxy**

From the client side:

Client  ->  proxy -> Server

From the server side:

Client  ->  Server

**Reverse proxy**

From the client side:

Client  ->  Server

From the server side:

Client  ->  proxy -> Server

So I think if it set up by a client user，it is called a proxy； if it set up by a server manager it is a reverse proxy.

Because the purposes and reasons for setting it up are different, they deal with data in different ways and use different software.

```
   User side          |      Server side
client  <->  proxy  <-->  reverse_proxy <-> real server
```

Comment: It would be better if its Graphical Representation but nice content.@tinyhare

Answer (score 3):

Looking from the perspective of the user: when sending a request to a *proxy* or *reverse proxy* server:

- *proxy* - requires **two arguments**: 
  1) what to get and 2) which proxy server to use an intermediate
- *reverse proxy* - requires **one argument**: 
  1) what to get

A reverse proxy fetches contents from another server unbeknownst to the user and **returns the result as if it originated from the reverse proxy server**.

Answer (score 1):

Most of the previous answers are good, but in my opinion none comes very close to addressing well enough the "reverse" quality that differentiates the two. To do that, some way of visualizing the "reverse" nature of what is essentially the same thing (a proxy) needs to be given, and it needs to be given in a well abstracted way.

A *proxy* (implicitly "forward proxy") connects multiple local clients to any one remote server:

```
c--
   |--p--s
c--
```

A *reverse proxy* connects multiple local servers to any one remote client (notice how the layout reverses):

```
s--
   |--p--c
s--
```

It is a matter of perspective really and properly understanding the concept requires abstracting away non-essential (to the particular concept) details though they may be very important when it comes to the pragmatics of proxy operation. Such details include the fact that in both scenarios the reality is that multiple clients connect to multiple servers, that clients and servers may not really be local or remote, where the Internet cloud is located or what kind of visibility exists between client and server.

Comment: "multiple local servers to any one remote client" - hm, why not multiple servers to multiple clients? I mean - the server itself does not connect to clients anyway, it only responds to any client requests, no matter if those are multiple clients or the same single client.

Comment: Read again - especially the last paragraph and try to understand "any one remote client" as one of many instances of operation

Comment: The text is ok, it's just that the second diagram made me suddenly think "hey, where did the other client go?" when I compared it to the first diagram.

Comment: Yeah, it's because that client is not any of the other two. Developers tend to think in very concrete and specific terms because this is what helps when you're implementing stuff however that same way of thinking is not very helpful when thinking about abstractions.

Answer (score 0):

Let's consider the purpose of the service.

In forward proxy:

Proxy helps **user** to access server.

In reverse proxy:

Proxy helps **server** to be accessed by user.

In the latter case, the one who is helped by the proxy is no longer a user, but a server, that's the reason why we call it a **reverse** proxy.