# Recommend a proxy server which has reverse proxy function

Tags: proxy, reverse-proxy, dynamic-proxy

In my application, both the server and client are hosted by myself, each client has a configuration which can configure the server it should connect, the communication is based on HTTP. Now, I get a requirement that the connect server of client should be able changed dynamically, but to change the server url configuration will require restart client which will take several minutes. So I want to add a proxy server between the clients and servers which can forward request from different client to different server by some rules.

I can not add a reverse proxy server as I can not distinguish the request from different client, because my proxy server will have only one domain name and I can not add parameter to the request URL of client.

But I can change the client to force it use proxy.

So my plan is set proxy for the clients, for each client, specify a unreal server url, the proxy server get the server url in the request and then forward request to a real server by rules.

Is there any server can do such things? and of cause, it will be better if can change rules without restart proxy server

Answer (score 1):

I take this links from this good anwser, just right here in SO

- [Difference between proxy server and reverse proxy server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/224664/difference-between-proxy-server-and-reverse-proxy-server#answer-366212)

all the credits to [qyb2zm302](https://stackoverflow.com/users/44862/qyb2zm302) for this list, and i recommend you [squid](http://www.squid-cache.org/) or [nginx](http://nginx.net/)

### reverse proxy software for HTTP (server side)

- [apache mod_proxy](http://wiki.apache.org/cocoon/ApacheModProxy)
- [squid](http://www.squid-cache.org/)
- [nginx](http://nginx.net/)  (written by russians, used on hulu.com, spam sites, etc.)
- [HAProxy](http://haproxy.1wt.eu/)
- [lighthttpd](http://redmine.lighttpd.net/projects/lighttpd)
- [perlbal](http://www.danga.com/perlbal/) (written for livejournal)
- [pound](http://www.apsis.ch/pound/)
- [varnish cache](http://varnish.projects.linpro.no/) (written by a freebsd kernel guru)

Answer (score 0):

I think the use of the HTTP header [X-Forwarded-For](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-Forwarded-For) may help.

Comment: However I am not able to add header to HTTP request. I can only config the server url and proxy server