# Azure Storage Blob : https://(storageAccountName).blob.core.windows.net/vhd?restype=container&comp=list not working using proxy

Tags: java, azure, azure-blob-storage

For getting the blob container details we are using the below mentioned REST API.
Vhd is the blob container name.

`https://(storageAccountName).blob.core.windows.net/vhd?restype=container&comp=list`

When we use proxy server details (example:SQUID Proxy) to access the storage REST API calls, we are getting the below mentioned error.

> HttpResponse for Blobs::  `ResourceNotFound`The
>   specified resource does not exist.
>   RequestId:6dc7e6f2-0001-000d-30f9-d56eb3000xxx

If we access the same rest api without proxy server, we are getting the valid response and it's working.

Comment: Based on your question, it seems like the proxy is the important part. And you didn't include any details of said proxy. This also seems better suited for ServerFault vs StackOverflow, due to it being infrastructure-related (but again, hard to tell without additional details of the proxy or any network captures).

Comment: What programming language (C#, PHP etc.) are you using? My guess is that you would need to specify proxy settings somewhere but the answer would depend on your execution environment.

Comment: we are using java and proxy setting is valid it's working for other REST API's. The REST API's which we are using for getting storage account,storage keys are working with proxy server. The squid proxy is like (10.10.10.10) to access pass all request via proxy.

Comment: please update on this.

Answer (score 1):

Per my experience, normally, using squid is as reverse proxy for backend services, but here you want to access the storage REST APIs via squid as forward proxy. You can refer to the wiki page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_server, the SO thread [Difference between proxy server and reverse proxy server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/224664/difference-between-proxy-server-and-reverse-proxy-server) and the [blog](http://www.jscape.com/blog/bid/87783/Forward-Proxy-vs-Reverse-Proxy) to know the differences between both.

So the solution for the issue is that configuring the proxy server as forward proxy.

1. For Squid, you can try to refer to the squid wiki pages http://wiki.squid-cache.org/SquidFaq/ConfiguringSquid and http://wiki.squid-cache.org/Features/HTTPS to know how to configure as forword proxy with HTTPS.
2. For Apache, you can try to refer to the apache doc page http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_proxy.html#forwardreverse to do.

Then, setting the system properties for Java to enable proxy support after setting up forward proxy successfully.

There are two ways support proxy for Java.

1. Command Line JVM Settings: The proxy settings are given to the JVM via command line arguments:

   ```
   java -Dhttp.proxyHost=proxyhostURL -Dhttp.proxyPort=proxyPortNumber -Dhttp.proxyUser=someUserName -Dhttp.proxyPassword=somePassword HelloWorldClass
   ```
2. Setting System Properties in Code: Adding the following lines in your Java code so that JVM uses the proxy to make HTTP calls.

   ```
   System.setProperty("http.proxyPort", "someProxyPort");
   System.setProperty("http.proxyUser", "someUserName");
   System.setProperty("http.proxyPassword", "somePassword");
   System.setProperty("http.proxyHost", "someProxyURL");
   ```

More information for Networking & Proxies & Properties in Java, Please refer to http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/net/proxies.html and http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/net/properties.html.

Answer (score 1):

we got the solution. The issue is we are invoking asynchronous calls for all storage accounts at a time. For example : if we have 5 storage accounts and each storage accounts 5 vhd containers and in for loop if we invoke all 5 at time and with callback waiting for 5 response,In this case it's not working. so we are invoking each call separately and it's started working.