# Does a reverse proxy defeat the geographical benefits of a CDN?

Tags: amazon-web-services, proxy, reverse-proxy, cdn

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/224664/difference-between-proxy-server-and-reverse-proxy-server/366212#366212) has a great explanation of a reverse proxy, but if all requests go though a single server in front of a CDN, doesn't this defeat the purpose of having many CDN locations?

For context, I have a completely static website on a CDN but need to separate mobile traffic by user agent and handle those requests with a another server.

Edit: the site is hosted on Netlify, which I believe uses Cloudfront

Will routing all requests through a reverse proxy affect performance?

Comment: Which CDN and what kind of technology it employs is relevant to this question.  The reverse proxy *in front of* the CDN would of course almost completely defeat the purpose of the CDN, which is why you'd put it *behind* the CDN... in fact, you could even distribute multiple reverse proxies geographically... depending on the CDN.  Please provide more detail on your scenario, present and future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, using a reverse proxy in a single location in front will defeat the purpose of using a CDN.

Your best bet is to use your reverse proxy as your origin in cloudfront and [forward the appropriate application headers](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/RequestAndResponseBehaviorCustomOrigin.html#request-custom-user-agent-header) then use your reverse proxy to decide what page to render based on those headers