# Docker as a Proxy server for a web service

Tags: docker, proxy

My app integrates with a web service that supports a proxy server. So I need to have integration tests that prove that works.

So I wanted to use Docker to create a local proxy server that I can run real integration tests to verify that my web service can be called through the proxy interface without errors.

So I tried https://github.com/jwilder/nginx-proxy

I started up the container with:

```
docker run -d -p 80:80 -v /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock:ro jwilder/nginx-proxy
```

When I use it i get a 503 error `503 Service Temporarily Unavailable`

Am I misunderstanding what this proxy does?

Comment: I think this is more close to what you are looking for: https://github.com/sameersbn/docker-squid

Comment: that should be the answer to this question. it worked for me.

Comment: I ran 
`docker run --name squid -d --restart=always   --publish 3128:3128   --volume /srv/docker/squid/cache:/var/spool/squid3   sameersbn/squid:3.3.8-22`
I can now test my web service proxy integration by using proxy host/port `docker_container.host:docker_container.port(3128)`

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Although this has been resolved in the comments, I'll try to answer the following question:

> Am I misunderstanding what this proxy does?

Yes. What your project requires, is the availability of a forward-proxy and what you are trying to use, is a reverse-proxy. This will become more clear once you go through the most top rated answers at [Difference between proxy server and reverse proxy server](https://stackoverflow.com/q/224664/1005215)

For a TL;DR moment:

[image]

There are many forward-proxy software available. You could choose any one of them for your project. Some of them are:

- [Squid](https://github.com/sameersbn/docker-squid)
- [Polipo](https://github.com/clue/docker-polipo)
- [Apache Traffic Server](https://github.com/sqawasmi/trafficserver-docker)
- [Privoxy](https://hub.docker.com/r/jess/privoxy/)
- [TinyProxy](https://github.com/francisbesset/docker-tinyproxy)

Comment: Yep definitely. awesome info i love all the links.

Comment: in 24 hours i'll reward you bounty of 50+ extra