# How to connect From Web Server to Database Server via App Server

Tags: spring, web-services, spring-boot

I developed a web application in spring boot which can deployed from a webserver in tomcat and connects to database server directly.But now I have to switch to a another database which is not accessible from the webserver.So I was advised to follow the pattern

```
Web Server -> App Server -> Database Server
```

But I am not sure How to convert my web app into this format.Becuse current my format is

```
Web Server -> Database Server
```

Could anyone explain how to implement this.Any help is appreciated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have some misunderstanding with Web Server and Application Server. Read more at [What is the difference between application server and web server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/936197/what-is-the-difference-between-application-server-and-web-server)

The communication structure would be something like

> Edge Server -> Internal Server -> Database

Now, your problem can be resolved by moving your current api to internal server which can directly connect to DB and create a pseudo api in Edge Server which just calls the api from Internal Server and sends response back to the client.

> Pseudo API -> Actual API -> Database

Comment: As you mentioned in the link My Previous Scenario is ***Scenario 1: Web server without an application server*** 
and I have to switch that to ***Scenario 2: Web server with an application server***.So I will be having to intoduce a business model in My Application.Am I correct?

Comment: I didn't understand your question, are you just introducing just a reverse proxy or what?

Comment: in case of just reverse proxy check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/224664/difference-between-proxy-server-and-reverse-proxy-server

Comment: I have doubt that now I have to run two apps where