# Is it possible to configure NGINX in a way it will work as browser proxy?

Tags: nginx, proxy

I am looking for a way to redirect all the trafic from my FireFox browser to a HTTP/HTTPS proxy server. Is it possible to configure Nginx as a proxy that I specify in the browser proxy settings?

[image: browser proxy settings]

Comment: This requires [a forward proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/224664/difference-between-proxy-server-and-reverse-proxy-server). `nginx` would not be a good choice.

Comment: what software can be used on Ubuntu Linux?

Comment: Last time I looked, [Squid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squid_(software)) was the popular solution.