# Redirect from subdomain to domain index

Tags: php, cpanel

I have domain (http://example.com) where the contents of the main domain is placed inside public_html and my subdomain (eg.example.com) where the contents of that subdomain is placed in a separate folder outside public_html.

I want to redirect the subdomain to main domain index.php without altering the browsing url. How to solve this problem.

Comment: you can do this by reverse proxy https://stackoverflow.com/questions/224664/difference-between-proxy-server-and-reverse-proxy-server

Comment: do you want to redirect or execute the index.php that is in the main domain?

if you just want to execute, you can do `require('../public_html/index.php');`

Comment: I want to execute the index.php that is in the main domain. but the url should remains unchanged (eg : http://eg.example.com) @new_user